# Tableau - Excluding from Grand Total

Tags: tableau-api

I have a report below that contains a gran total, but the Grand Total needs to exclude L-CTRx column. I tried creating a calculated field `SUM(IIF([Line Of Business] <> "L-CTRx", [Total_Count],0))`, but when I add it in the Column shelf it didn't provide the result I'm expecting.

[image]

Comment: Is Grand Total a calculated field with your provided formula?

Comment: No. It is coming from the analysis menu. My user wants to see the above row, but less the L-CTRx total from the Grand Total. What I did so far is created a filter with the same layout about and it works. I was just mirroring the report I did in SSRS and see if I can mimic it in Tableau.

Comment: Are each one of the above fields their own measure?

Comment: The only measure is the numeric values the Headers are dimensions.